# How to pre-populate a groupBox in Win Forms C#?

Tags: c#, winforms

We're doing C# this week. It's the Lunch Order assignment, and the groupBox for my Add-ons menu does not populate until I check another main course. The Add-ons are all Checkboxes inside the groupBox.

I thought I would overcome this by setting the first main course item (hamburger) as checked by default. Did not fix it, and so I thought maybe I should have one of the add-on menu check-boxes checked by default... This also did not improve anything.
This is what it looks like when I run the app:

[LunchOrderLaunch No add-ons](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZHvWo.png)

And when I check another main course option:

[LunchOrderMainCourseChange Add-ons show](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FG7t8.png)

Here's the code (yes things are out of order because I am new to this and trying to work around things. Apologies for that in advance:

```
 using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace LunchAppLAB1_V2
{
    public partial class frmLunchOrder : Form
    {
        // Global declaration
        decimal Subtotal;
        decimal Tax = 0.05m;
        decimal OrderTotal;

        public frmLunchOrder()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void grbxAddOns_CheckChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void btnExit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string message = "Hey! Thanks for dining with us today!\n Will you be coming 
            back?";
            DialogResult button =
                MessageBox.Show(message, "Dear Customer",
                MessageBoxButtons.YesNo,
                MessageBoxIcon.Information);

            if (button == DialogResult.No)
            {
                this.Close();
            }
            if (button == DialogResult.Yes)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Hey! Thanks dude! Hope to see you soon!", "Greeting 
                Message");
                this.Close();
            }
        }

        private void btnPlaceOrder_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            decimal add = 0m;
            if (chkbx1.Checked)
            {
                add++;
            }
            if (chkbx2.Checked)
            {
                add++;
            }
            if (chkbx3.Checked)
            {
                add++;
            }
            if (rdoHamburger.Checked)
            {
                decimal Hamburger = Convert.ToDecimal(rdoHamburger.Checked);
                Hamburger = 6.95m;

                Subtotal = Hamburger + (add * .75m);
                Tax = Subtotal * 0.05m;
                OrderTotal = Tax + Subtotal;

                txtSubtotal.Text = Subtotal.ToString("c");
                txtTax.Text = Tax.ToString("c");
                txtOrderTotal.Text = OrderTotal.ToString("c");
            }
            else if (rdoPizza.Checked)
            {
                decimal Pizza = Convert.ToDecimal(rdoPizza.Checked);
                Pizza = 5.95m;

                Subtotal = Pizza + (add * .50m);
                Tax = Subtotal * 0.05m;
                OrderTotal = Tax + Subtotal;

                txtSubtotal.Text = Subtotal.ToString("c");
                txtTax.Text = Tax.ToString("c");
                txtOrderTotal.Text = OrderTotal.ToString("c");
            }
            else if (rdoSalad.Checked)
            {
                decimal Salad = Convert.ToDecimal(rdoSalad.Checked);
                Salad = 4.95m;

                Subtotal = Salad + (add * .25m);
                Tax = Subtotal * 0.05m;
                OrderTotal = Tax + Subtotal;

                txtSubtotal.Text = Subtotal.ToString("c");
                txtTax.Text = Tax.ToString("c");
                txtOrderTotal.Text = OrderTotal.ToString("c");
            }
        }

        private void rdoHamburger_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            grbxAddOns.Text = "Add-on items($.75/each)";
            chkbx1.Text = "Lettuce, Tomato, and Onions";
            chkbx2.Text = "Ketchup, Mustard, and Mayonnaise";
            chkbx3.Text = "French Fries";
        }

        private void rdoPizza_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            grbxAddOns.Text = "Add-on items($.50/each)";
            chkbx1.Text = "Pepperoni";
            chkbx2.Text = "Sausage";
            chkbx3.Text = "Olives";
        }

        private void rdoSalad_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            grbxAddOns.Text = "Add-on items($.25/each)";
            chkbx1.Text = "Croutons";
            chkbx2.Text = "Bacon Bits";
            chkbx3.Text = "Bread Sticks";
        }

        private void btnReset_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            RecursiveClearTextBoxes(this.Controls);
        }

        private void RecursiveClearTextBoxes(Control.ControlCollection cc)
        {
            foreach (Control ctrl in cc)
            {
                TextBox tb = ctrl as TextBox;
                if (tb != null)
                    tb.Clear();
                else
                    RecursiveClearTextBoxes(ctrl.Controls);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

All of the radio buttons for the main course option have been coded with a CheckedChanged instruction. So I understand that they don't fire until the button is physically checked (and the checked button changes) So I am wondering how to do this and have the add-ons populate to begin with. I've been trying to find a solution since yesterday, and now I'm pretty much out of time. I'm a C# noob with this assignment due tomorrow...

Comment: Gus's posted answer will work but you can also do it without manually triggering the event. To do this, you wouldn't set any option as checked in the designer and instead in your constructor you would set the item as checked, e.g. `rdoHamburger.Checked = true;`. When your form loads the `rdoHamburger` option will be set and this alone will trigger the event.

Comment: Nice, I may try that down the road. Gus' solution worked that way too. When I launch the app The Hamburger radio is checked (by default) and the add-ons are populating. I removed the checked default on the add on chkbx1 so all the Add-on options are populated, but none are pre-chosen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the constructor, add this line *after* InitializeComponent();

```
public frmLunchOrder()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    rdoHamburger_CheckedChanged(null, null); // <-- this line
}
```

Your problem is that, even though you're setting one to be clicked by default, it's still not firing the event that sets the check box text.

So you can just call this event manually in the constructor.

Comment: And that's how easy it is when you know how...
Thank you Gus. That works Perfectly!

Comment: Rather than passing nulls you can use this call, which I think is a little better... `radioButton1_CheckedChanged(this, EventArgs.Empty);`

Comment: @quaabaam agreed, but ordinarily the `sender` would be the button, so how about `radioButton1_CheckedChanged(this.radioButton1, EventArgs.Empty)` as long as we're trying to make the call consistently? I like your first comment above even better, though.

Comment: @IVSoftware You are correct, my mistake.